# How to kill active connections based on DB_NAME using SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am currently connected to a customer database via the front end using there application and I run the following query which displays active connections:

```
SELECT DB_NAME(DBID) AS DBNAME,
       COUNT(DBID)   AS NUMBEROFCONNECTIONS,
       LOGINAME      AS LOGINNAME
FROM   SYS.SYSPROCESSES
WHERE  DBID > 0
GROUP  BY DBID, LOGINAME
```

I have the ability to run SQL in the front end of the application therefore how can i kill all active connections based on a `DB_NAME(DBID) = 'CustomerDB'`
using SQL?

Comment: Extract the SPID and use it in a KILL command

Comment: I found an answer on a single click, did you really try to research ?

Answer (score 0):

`KILL` command may not work for the newly established connection. You can try taking the database to `Single_User` mode rather using an `ALTER` statement like

```
ALTER DATABASE CustomerDB
SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
```

Answer (score -1):

```
USE master
GO

DECLARE @kill varchar(8000) = '';
SELECT @kill = @kill + 'kill ' + CONVERT(varchar(5), spid) + ';'
FROM master..sysprocesses 
WHERE dbid = db_id('MyDB')

EXEC(@kill);
```

Credits: [Script to kill all connections to a database (More than RESTRICTED_USER ROLLBACK)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7197574/script-to-kill-all-connections-to-a-database-more-than-restricted-user-rollback)

Comment: This should be flagged as duplicate, not posted as your own answer.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas , yup i posted it because it seems that the person who ask did not try to research on his own, so im trying to help.. that's why i put credits.. yup i also flagged this question as duplicate.

Comment: @Japz Divino: You are rude

Comment: @PriceCheaperton my bad, because i tried to research when i read your question, and i found an answer here also in stackoverflow site, so i was wondering if you really tried to search. anyways my apologies if i offended you in my comment.

Comment: No probs................