# Unable to restore database to a snapshot in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-restore, snapshot-isolation

I want to create a database snapshot and restore database to it every time a unit test is run. I am able to create snapshot but while restoring it, I encounter the error below while doing it.

> Msg 5070, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Database state cannot be changed while other users are using the database 'ImportData'
>
> Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

The SQL queries for creating and reverting database to snapshot are listed below.

Create snapshot:

```
CREATE DATABASE Data_SShot
ON (NAME=Data,
    FILENAME='C:\Snapshot\DataSnapshot.ss'),
   (NAME=Data_Data1,
    FILENAME='C:\Snapshot\Data1Snapshot.ss'),
   (NAME=Data_Index1,
    FILENAME='C:\Snapshot\DataIndexSnapshot.ss')
AS SNAPSHOT OF Data
```

Restore to snapshot

```
use master
go

RESTORE DATABASE Data 
FROM DATABASE_SNAPSHOT = 'Data_SShot'
```

It states that

> Database state cannot be changed while other users are using the database

How to overcome this problem? I am using .NET (C#) to do this. How to close connection to run `RESTORE DATABASE` successfully?

I want this entire process of creating snapshot and reverting DB to it later to happen for each test in test suite.

Comment: [This SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7197574/script-to-kill-all-connections-to-a-database-more-than-restricted-user-rollback) going to help, I think.

Comment: you need to take the database offline first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are few things which need to be done before restoring the DB.

> 1. Get the number of active users for the DB and kill the sessions.
> 2. Take the DB offline and online which will terminate all hidden connections.
> 3. Now restore the DB. If it fails, then take the DB offline and try to restore.
> 4. Once restore is done, bring the DB online.

These are the steps which I have been using for DB restore and it's worked for me for a long time.

Comment: This doesn't work.  It results in an error on step 3: Database cannot be reverted. Either the primary or the snapshot names are improperly specified, all other snapshots have not been dropped, or there are missing files.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

```
ALTER DATABASE [Data] SET SINGLE_USER

RESTORE DATABASE Data 
FROM DATABASE_SNAPSHOT = 'Data_SShot'

ALTER DATABASE [Data] SET MULTI_USER WITH NO_WAIT
```