# How to find all the session for particular plan_handle or sql_hash in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, session, sql-server-2012, ssms

How to find all the session for particular plan_handle or sql_hash in SQL Server?

Comment: Does [`sys.dm_exec_requests`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-requests-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) help? Perhaps adding some details to your "question", e.g. the results you expect and what you've tried, would help us help you.

Comment: i want to kill those all running session who is related to specific plan_handle or sql_hash for my one of the task.I already tried to use sys.dm_exec_requests dmv but it always showing null. Is there any other way to find session?

Comment: Here is the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37252753/automatically-kill-session-of-some-specific-task/55752789#55752789