# SQLAlchemy engine.execute() leaves a connection to the database in sleeping status

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, pymssql

I am using SQL server database. I've noticed that when executing the code below, I get a connection to the database left over in 'sleeping' state with an 'AWAITING COMMAND' status.

```
    engine = create_engine(url, connect_args={'autocommit': True})
    res = engine.execute(f"CREATE DATABASE my_database")
    res.close()
    engine.dispose()
```

With a breakpoint after the `engine.dispose()` call, I can see an entry on the server in the `EXEC sp_who2` table. This entry only disappears after I kill the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically want to kill all the connections You could use something like this:

For MS SQL Server 2012 and above

```
USE [master];

DECLARE @kill varchar(8000) = '';  
SELECT @kill = @kill + 'kill ' + CONVERT(varchar(5), session_id) + ';'  
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions
WHERE database_id  = db_id('MyDB')

EXEC(@kill);
```

For MS SQL Server 2000, 2005, 2008

```
USE master;

DECLARE @kill varchar(8000); SET @kill = '';  
SELECT @kill = @kill + 'kill ' + CONVERT(varchar(5), spid) + ';'  
FROM master..sysprocesses  
WHERE dbid = db_id('MyDB')

EXEC(@kill);
```

Or something more script-like:

```
DECLARE @pid SMALLINT, @sql NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE curs CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY FOR
  SELECT DISTINCT pid FROM master..sysprocesses where dbid = DB_ID(@dbname)
OPEN curs
fetch next from curs into @pid
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @sql = 'KILL ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @pid)
    EXEC(@sql)
    FETCH NEXT FROM curs into @pid
END
CLOSE curs
DEALLOCATE curs
```

More can be found here:
[Script to kill all connections to a database (More than RESTRICTED_USER ROLLBACK)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7197574/script-to-kill-all-connections-to-a-database-more-than-restricted-user-rollback)

Answer (score 1):

Probably [Connection Pooling](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/pooling.html)

> Connection Pooling
>
> A connection pool is a standard technique used to
>   maintain long running connections in memory for efficient re-use, as
>   well as to provide management for the total number of connections an
>   application might use simultaneously.
>
> Particularly for server-side web applications, a connection pool is
>   the standard way to maintain a “pool” of active database connections
>   in memory which are reused across requests.
>
> SQLAlchemy includes several connection pool implementations which
>   integrate with the Engine. They can also be used directly for
>   applications that want to add pooling to an otherwise plain DBAPI
>   approach.

.

> I'm not sure if this is what gets in the way of my teardown method which drops the database

To drop a database that's possibly in use try:

```
USE master;
ALTER DATABASE mydb SET RESTRiCTED_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
DROP DATABASE mydb;
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure if this is what gets in the way of my teardown method which drops the database - I get "database in use" error which I assume is a sleeping connection from the pool. Not sure if I can time these out.